# C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows-7, pycallgraph

Hi after installing code2flow , the process has finish successfully

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating code2flow.egg-info
writing code2flow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to code2flow.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to code2flow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'code2flow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'code2flow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'docs'
writing manifest file 'code2flow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\code2flowlib
copying code2flowlib\dotgenerator.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib
copying code2flowlib\engine.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib
copying code2flowlib\mutablestring.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib
copying code2flowlib\nesting.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib
copying code2flowlib\__init__.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib
creating build\lib\testscripts
copying testscripts\pysimple.py -> build\lib\testscripts
copying testscripts\pysimple2.py -> build\lib\testscripts
copying testscripts\pysimple3.py -> build\lib\testscripts
copying testscripts\urllib2.py -> build\lib\testscripts
copying testscripts\__init__.py -> build\lib\testscripts
creating build\lib\code2flowlib\languages
copying code2flowlib\languages\javascript.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib\languages
copying code2flowlib\languages\python.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib\languages
copying code2flowlib\languages\__init__.py -> build\lib\code2flowlib\languages
creating build\bdist.win32
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\dotgenerator.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\engine.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\languages\javascript.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\languages\python.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\languages\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\mutablestring.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\nesting.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
copying build\lib\code2flowlib\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
copying build\lib\testscripts\pysimple.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
copying build\lib\testscripts\pysimple2.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
copying build\lib\testscripts\pysimple3.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
copying build\lib\testscripts\urllib2.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
copying build\lib\testscripts\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\dotgenerator.py to dotgenerator.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\engine.py to engine.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages\javascript.py to javascript.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages\python.py to python.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\languages\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\mutablestring.py to mutablestring.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\nesting.py to nesting.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\code2flowlib\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts\pysimple.py to pysimple.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts\pysimple2.py to pysimple2.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts\pysimple3.py to pysimple3.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts\urllib2.py to urllib2.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\testscripts\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
installing scripts to build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
running install_scripts
running build_scripts
creating build\scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting code2flow -> build\scripts-2.7
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\code2flow -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
copying code2flow.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying code2flow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying code2flow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying code2flow.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist\code2flow-0.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing code2flow-0.2-py2.7.egg
Copying code2flow-0.2-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding code2flow 0.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing code2flow script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\code2flow-0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for code2flow==0.2
Finished processing dependencies for code2flow==0.2
```

When trying a simple run i get this error

```
$ code2flow
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/code2flow': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The problem is that the script folder contain code2flow ... but i get this error also when i have installed pyCallGraph

Mt python version is

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.7
```

- I'm on windows 7

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run it as

> python code2flow